# Get MB used and row count of filtered records of all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a query in SQL Server.
I want to get the total count and the used disk space of records created in year 2020 (I have a column `SysDateCreate` in all tables) for each table.
I want a 'table result' like this:

```
| Year | TableName | TotalRowCont | Total_MB |
```

And I wrote this query:

```
SELECT
    NULL AS Year,
    sys.tables.name AS TableName, 
    MAX(sys.partitions.rows) AS TotalRowCount,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(sys.allocation_units.used_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Used_Mb,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(sys.allocation_units.total_pages) - SUM(sys.allocation_units.used_pages)) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Unused_Mb,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(sys.allocation_units.total_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Total_Mb
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions ON sys.indexes.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id AND sys.indexes.index_id = sys.partitions.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units ON sys.partitions.partition_id = sys.allocation_units.container_id
WHERE sys.tables.name LIKE 'Tb%' 
GROUP BY sys.tables.name
ORDER BY sys.tables.name
```

How can I filter/group by year?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"How Can I filter/group by year?"* you don't. The pages of the database have no idea what "year" that data is related to. If your tables have been partitioned by year then you could, however, filter to that partition but your query suggests that is not the case.

Comment: Side note, 3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated and should be avoided. Stick to giving your objects aliases and use those to qualify your columns.

Comment: Be aware the most granular unit of space allocation is an 8K page. A page may contain rows for different years, shared overhead, etc. For your need, I suggest you compute the total space for each table and apply a percentage based on the row count by `SysCreateDate`.